# Magento 1.9 - Media.phtml not showing on configurable products view page

Tags: product, configurable-product, media

I have recently been learning the ways of magento, and up until two days ago it was all going great, but then I started learning about different product types .eg Simple, Bundle, Configurable. So anyway i needed to create a configurable product for a plain t-shirt, which had an option for colour and size. I added the image as i would any other product and made sure it was in-stock and done everything i would have done with a simple product, assigned the simple products and everything seemed fine. So i went on to my front end and it shows fine in the category page which its in but when i go to the actual viewing page for the product the Media.phtml file seems to be missing. The main image isn't there and inside the product-img-box div there seems to be nothing there (where my media loads for every other product).

Any help would be appreciated, i have searched everywhere for some sort of answer but haven't found a thing.

Thanks in advance, Josh.

Comment: if you turn on template hints does it actually try to load a file?

Comment: No it doesn't show it loading media.phtml, however it loads for every other product, just not configurable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking permission issue.  A common issue is having wrong permissions on the media directory.

To rule that out you need to do two things.

Change the ownership of all your files to your web server's user.  That's usually www-data, but it varies by web server and linux distribution.

the command will look something like this...

```
chown www-data:www-data -R magento
```

chown changes permission www-data:www-data sets the user and group. -R means recursive.  magento is the root directory wherever you have your magento file.

after that got through this.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions

pay close attention to the instructions.  You need a blackslash before the semicolon on the find command.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice, I am currently editing my site on a local server so would this still apply?

Comment: Yes.  Be careful here. Just remember when moving files to production you might have similar issues.  Making the web user own the files solves a lot of problems.